# Phone JS with Steroids js

Tags: javascript, steroids, phonejs

Would Steroids JS be useful in a Phone JS project? or do they do similar things? Since my project involves there being native UI for each platform the app is on, I thought Phone JS might be a good solution and Phone JS also focuses on better performance so does that mean it may be unnecessary to also use Steroids JS to enhance performance?

Comment: In case you haven't made up your mind yet, you can take a look at the article I wrote about SteroidsJS a while back that could give you an overview of their solution: http://marcgg.com/blog/2013/08/29/appgyver-steroids-iphone-hybrid-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Would Steroids JS be useful in a Phone JS project? or do they do similar things?`

They do similar things. Both of these are platforms that leverage PhoneGap/Cordova to build hybrid mobile apps that use Native UI elements to create more native feeling and responsive apps.

I have not used PhoneJS, but I have used SteroidsJS heavily for the past 8 months. From what I know about SteroidsJS and from what I have quickly read on PhoneJS, you will not be able to use these together, and you probably wouldn't anyway since they are both trying to do the same thing.

You should consider a couple things before you decide which one to go with:

1. Cost: PhoneJS starts at $199 per developer/year (though it is free for non-commercial projects) and SteroidsJS starts at $0.
2. Users: PhoneJS currently supports iOS, Android, Windows, and Tizen while Steroids only supports iOS and Android, but their current support of Android is [not great](https://github.com/AppGyver/scanner/issues/35), though they are rebuilding it from the ground up.

If you do go with SteroidsJS, you do have to go in knowing that it still a relatively young project and that it is still growing, but it has a lot of potential.